# jquery datepicker ui and end date

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker

I am trying to fire an ajax command off when i get the results of the to and from date via the jquery ui datepicker.  I get the "from" date just fine, the "to" date is always undefined, no matter what i do. any ideas?

```
 function getInfo()
 {
var beg = $("#from").val();
var end = $("to").val();
 alert($("to").val());     <-----this is always undefined
    $("#cdrData").hide();
        $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "cdrs/getCDRS.php",
                   data: "begDate=" + beg + "&endDate=" + end,
                   success: function(result){
                     $("#cdrData").html(result);
 $("#cdrData").slideDown('slow');

                   }
                 });
 }
```

And the php form:

```
 <form method='POST' id='getCDRS' name='getCDRS'>
 <label for="from">From</label>
 <input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
 <label for="to">to</label>
 <input type="text" id="to" name="to" />
 <input type='button' value='submit' onclick="getInfo()";>
 </form>
```

and the standard datepicker script:

```
 <script>
 $(function() {
$( "#from" ).datepicker({
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  changeMonth: true,
  numberOfMonths: 3,
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
  }
});
$( "#to" ).datepicker({
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  changeMonth: true,
  numberOfMonths: 3,
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
  }
});
   });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is missing `#`

```
var end = $("#to").val();
alert($("#to").val());
```

Comment: that was a c/p error.  I have added the # and get same result.  Thanks for the keen eye though....

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this jsFiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/de3Hf/2/

I have cleaned the scope and it works like a charm. The #to date is also filled:

this is what I did:

```
function getInfo()
 {
    var beg = $("#from").val();
    var end = $("#to").val();
     alert(end);
 }
```

*p.s. maybe this is not the right question, since it's quite simple to get the to date filled, could there be something wrong with ajax?*

Comment: I don't know what was wrong.  some small typo somewhere.  it is working now.

Comment: @Bart2puck Then accept the answer that helped you or make your own answer, so the question is closed.